# XSLT regular expression to remove sequences text

Tags: xslt

I have an XML, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <earth>
     <computer>
             <parts>;;remove;;This should stay;;remove too;;This stay;;yeah also remove;;this stay </parts>

       </computer>
    </earth>
```

I want to create an XSLT 2.0 transform to remove all text which starts and ends with `;;`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<earth>
     <computer>
            <parts>This should stay This stay this stay </parts>
      </computer>

    </earth>
```

Try to do something like this but no luck:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fn">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="parts">
  <xsl:element name="parts" >
                <xsl:value-of  select="replace(., ';;.*;;','')" />
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: .* is a greedy match; it will swallow all the ";;" delimiters up to the last one. You could replace it with a non-greedy match (.*?) or avoid matching semicolons as in the solution from @michael.hor257k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach would be tokenize on ";;" as separator, then remove all even-numbered tokens:

```
<xsl:template match="parts">
  <parts>
   <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(.,';;')[position() mod 2 = 1]"
     separator=""/>
  </parts>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This assumes that the first token always needs to removed - and will fail with an input such as `<parts>keep;;remove;;keep</parts>`.

Comment: I don't think so; surely both in that case and in the supplied case, the first "remove" is token 2?

Comment: I have re-checked this. The problem is that you have the parity reversed: it should be `[position() mod 2 = 1]`.

Comment: Thanks, yes. The intro "remove all even-numbered tokens" is correct, but the code as written retains all even-numbered tokens. Editing to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, what a dumb way to markup text. You have XML at your disposal, why not use it? And even if marking this way, why not use different symbols for opening and closing the marked parts?

Anyway, I believe this returns the expected result:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parts">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., ';;.+?;;', '')" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**XSLT 1.0**

For this kind of thing I'd use recursion. Just using string replace you can get what is before and after a certain character (or set of characters). All you need to do is continually loop over the string until there are no more occurrences of the replace character, like follows:

```
<xsl:template name="string-remove-between">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="remove" />

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $remove)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$remove)" />
            <xsl:call-template name="string-remove-between">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after(substring-after($text,$remove), $remove)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="remove" select="$remove" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you'd just call the template with your text and the section you want to remove:

```
<xsl:call-template name="string-remove-between">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="parts"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="remove">;;</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Note that there are **two** substring-after calls, this makes sure we get the **second** instance of the replace characters ';;' so we aren't pulling in the text between.

Comment: Thx, nice solution. I realized that the expected result I get this simply modification of my code (use reluctant quantifiers?): select="replace(., ';;.+?;;', '')"

Comment: Yeah I didn't realise in your question you mentioned it was XSLT 2.0, which I'm not as familiar with. I'll update my solution in case anyone else comes across this and is using 1.0.